# Gulfstream IV-SP Not Sending POS INIT to IRS 3

Tags: avionics

After powering up and starting up EFIS/ICAS, starting up both FMS’s, I try to POS INIT the IRS’s, but the IRS in position 3 does not receive a position. It’s like it’s on and waiting for it, but it only sends the position to IRS 1 and 2. Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Is this on a real aircraft or a payware flight simulator thing?